# How do I get a substring of a String object using a character position range?

Tags: rust

Say I have a struct Foo that owns a string:

```rust
struct Foo {
    owned_string: String
}
```

I want to implement some methods on this struct that return substrings from the owned String. For efficiency reasons, I don't want to allocate any new memory for this, I just want the return values to point to the original String.

Let's say I know the substring I want, it's characters 10 through 15.

I can't just slice it like `self.owned_string[10..16]`, since that would give me bytes, not characters.

I can take the characters and collect them into a new String object, like `self.owned_string.chars().skip(9).take(6).collect::<String>()`, but that creates a new String object. String objects own their strings (AFAIK), so presumably new memory was allocated for this, which is not what I want.

How do I create string slices that reference a substring of a String object, but using *character positions*? (Without allocating any new memory)

Comment: Strings don’t keep track of [Unicode scalar value] positions, so you’ll need to convert those indices to UTF-8 byte indices by iteration. Once that’s done, the byte slice will work.

Comment: While the answers you got are fine, you might consider examining why specifically you want to use character offsets. Use cases exist, but they are somewhat rare. I would instead encourage you to use byte offsets everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`char_indices()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) then slice the string according to the positions the iterator gives you:

```rust
let mut iter = s.char_indices();
let (start, _) = iter.nth(10).unwrap();
let (end, _) = iter.nth(5).unwrap();
let slice = &s[start..end];
```

However, note that [as mentioned in the documentation of `chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

> It’s important to remember that [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html) represents a Unicode Scalar Value, and might not match your idea of what a ‘character’ is. Iteration over grapheme clusters may be what you actually want. This functionality is not provided by Rust’s standard library, check crates.io instead.

Comment: Come to think of it... How would you convert a character position back into a byte position? In my case I'm slicing the string several times and it would probably be cheaper to do it by byte position. To clarify, if I do `let pos = s.chars().position {|x| x == '<'}?`, I'm left with the *character* position of '<', but I'm not guaranteed that `s[pos..]` will start at the '<', since there could be multi-byte characters in the string. Is it possible to convert "pos" to a *byte* index instead?

Comment: Use `char_indices()` and `find(|(_, x)| x == '<')?.0`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read your answer carefully enough. I thought `char_indices` made a new object that could be sliced by character position, but actually it maps character positions to byte positions. It's exactly what I'm looking for then 

Answer (score 1):

@ChayimFriedman's answer is of course correct, I just wanted to contribute a more telling example:

```rust
fn print_string(s: &str) {
    println!("String: {}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "".to_string();

    let mut iter = s.char_indices();

    // Retrieve the position of the char at pos 1
    let (start, _) = iter.nth(1).unwrap();

    // Now the next char will be at position `2`. Which would be
    // equivalent of querying `.next()` or `.nth(0)`.
    // So if we query for `nth(2)` we query 3 characters; meaning
    // the position of character 4.
    let (end, _) = iter.nth(2).unwrap();

    // Gives you a &str, which is exactly what you want.
    // A reference to a substring, zero allocations, zero overhead.
    let substring = &s[start..end];

    print_string(&s);
    print_string(substring);
}
```

```
String: 
String:
```

I've done it with smileys because smileys are definitely multi-byte unicode characters.

As @ChayimFriedman already noted, the reason why we have to iterate through the `char_indices` is because unicode characters are variably sized. They can be anywhere from 1 to 8 bytes long, so the only way to find out where the character boundaries are is to actually read the string up to the character we desire.